# Making a connection using rmongodb in R on Mac OS x

Tags: r, macos, rmongodb

I've been assigned to analyze some data that are contained in a MongoDB format. I'm a **complete newbie** to MongoDB, but I can manage if I can read the data and convert it to an R data table or data frame. If possible, I'd like to do just enough to get the MongoDB data into R.

I'm trying to get access to the data using the rmongodb package in R version 3.1.2 on Mac OS X Yosemite via RStudio 0.98.953. I've tried this so far:

```
install.packages("rmongodb")
library(rmongodb)
#up to here, it works
mongo <- mongo.create(host='localhost')
mongo <- mongo.create(host='127.0.0.1')
mongo <- mongo.create()
```

Each of the mongo <- assignment statements results in the same error:

> Unable to connect to localhost:27017, error code = 2

and

```
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
```

returns FALSE.

If this is an essential part of the answer, we can use "db=test" as the database. For what it's worth, the datasets are stored in "~/Desktop/MyExample" and consist of four files with the extension "bson" and their analogues ending with ".metadata.json", as well as a "system.indexes.bson" file.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the localhost is the default. Does it work if you omit the argument ? i.e. `require(rmongodb); m <- mongo.create();mongo.is.connected(m)` Also mongo defaults to storing its data under `/data/`. try running things from the shell (`mongo` at the command line). If that does not work, your mongo is either not installed or the daemon is not running.

Comment: What Hans said. You actually need to install Mongo for it to work, not just the R interface. I get precisely the same error messages running this code on a machine without Mongo, so I suspect that's your problem.

Comment: Mac OS X should be an easy installation from `http://www.mongodb.org/downloads`

Comment: Thanks, Hans and Oliver. You were right; I did not have Mongo installed. I followed the instructions that used Homebrew at this link (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) and got R to make the connection after I specified the proper dbpath. Thanks for your help!